# Reason behind crossed eyes of Gnana Saraswati Devi

Tags: scripture, goddess, saraswati, inner-meaning

In Sanatan Dharma, the forms and shapes of any goddess are not random. Great rishis experience the form and shape of Goddesses along with the knowledge of details of those particular forms and shapes. All the things that decorate, hold by and are surrounded by the Goddesses also contain certain semantics related to the manifestation.

[image]

I do hear about the hidden meanings of many entities related to Saraswati Devi such as aksharamala, Hamsa, Vedas, lotus, color, etc. If you look at the image of gnana Saraswati carefully, you can observe that she has crossed her Eyes or she contains cross eyes.

I didn't remember seeing any other Goddesses with Crossed Eyes and I know only Kubera has a [curse related to the eyes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16382/661), but it is in an entirely different context.

Do the scriptures comment on the crossed eyes of gnana Saraswati Devi? Is there any hidden meaning behind them?

Comment: interesting question

Comment: Thanks @YOuwillnotknow....